# Fridge / Freezer not cooling. No sound.

Tags: appliances, refrigerator, ice-maker

Short: My fridge was cold two days ago. Now it's not cold at all. Makes no sounds. Power is on and lights on.

Long:

- Fridge was in storage for unknown years, and filthy.
- Cleaned and plugged in. It got cold and ran well for maybe 1 day.
- Water dispenser (maybe) leaked. It looked like it may have been coming from the ice maker inside and trickling down. I didn't get to diagnose.
- Thermostat works. Says it's 70 deg.
- There's no ice anywhere: inside, outside, etc.
- There's no sounds. No fans, compressors, silent.
- There's a condensation tray underneath that has a lot of water in it.

I'm not sure what of this leads to the right answer, but I figured this is specific enough to pinpoint. Thanks team.

Comment: Shirtsleeve diagnosis: lots of water in the condensation tray indicates you missed observing a frozen coil, which generally means low Freon.

Comment: If it’s the coil on the back I easily could have. I left it off for a day unplugged. And now it’s working again. Maybe the coil thawed? Low Freon: does that mean there’s a leak? Or can it be age? It’s an 2004 fridge.

Answer (score 2):

Could be low on coolant (freon), or could be a thermo switch. If the thermostat for the coil is not functioning, then it will cause it to ice over and not defrost. This is an easy fix on most freezers. Just let the freezer thaw completely, don't chop or break ice off. It could also be the thermostat timer. If it is not advancing, then it is not sending a signal to the defrost heater to thaw the coil. Easy way to check this is to manually advance the timer and see if you hear anything happen. Wait about 30 minutes and see if something changes, like the fridge coming back on. This would indicate the timer is working or not.

Comment: Got something. It put itself in diagnostic mode. Results. 1-1 2-1 3-1 4-2 5-1. Looks like test 4 failed. I can’t find what the codes mean. Model kscs25inss00.

Comment: There should be 6 tests total. What I have read says that the test will display, followed by the water filter light. To enter diagnostic mode, unplug and re-plug the fridge and after 13 second, press power and the water filter buttons together for 3 seconds.

Comment: Press and holdbtge water filter reset button for 2 seconds or until it beeps to go to each test. Filter light indicates good (green) or failed (red). Cycle through all the tests and record the results. Test 1 is Freezer Thermistor, 2 is Fridge Thermistor, 3 is Evap Fan, 4 is Compressor and Condensor Fan, 5 is Air Baffle, 6 is Defrost Heater and Bi-metal, and 7 is Exit.

Comment: If your test is similar to what you posted, test 4 for Compressor and Condenser fan, it could be that the capacitor for the fan or the fan has gone bad, or the signal to them is bad (wiring issue or control board.) Time to test the fans and capacitor(s) and determine what it is. One way is to unplug it for 24 hours, then plug it in and listen for anything happening. If the compressor/fan make noise, the capacitor could be giving up and swelling, in the heat it wont want to work.